# Why avahi-browse doesn't list my link-local address when coupled with a static configuration?

Tags: networking, avahi

Given the following configuration:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
        iface eth0 inet static
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        address 192.168.0.25
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        post-up /usr/sbin/avahi-autoipd --force-bind --daemonize --wait $IFACE 2> /dev/null
        pre-down /usr/sbin/avahi-autoipd --kill $IFACE 2> /dev/null
```

I make the machine get a link-local address while still having an static configuration (for when this machine gets connected to LAN). The issue is that for now, it won't be attached to a LAN, I just want to access it using a network cable directly connecting two machines, and communicating through the given link-local addresses. Connection works, I can ssh it:

```
~ ❯❯❯ ssh francisco@169.254.5.135                                                                                                                  archlinux ✱
francisco@169.254.5.135's password:
  ____      _                 _ ____     __  __
 / ___|   _| |__   _____  __ (_)___ \ ___\ \/ /
| |  | | | | '_ \ / _ \ \/ / | | __) / _ \\  /
| |__| |_| | |_) | (_) >  <  | |/ __/  __//  \
 \____\__,_|_.__/ \___/_/\_\ |_|_____\___/_/\_\


Welcome to ARMBIAN Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 3.14.60-cubox

System load:   0.00             Up time:       35 min
Memory usage:  5 % of 3788Mb    IP:            192.168.0.25
CPU temp:      47°C
Usage of /:    4% of 29G

Last login: Wed Feb 24 04:19:27 2016 from 169.254.4.29
francisco@cubox-i:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:63:b4:00:88:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.5.135/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link eth0:avahi
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.25/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d263:b4ff:fe00:881f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether f6:4b:80:39:3e:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:ad:f8:1d:4b:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
francisco@cubox-i:~$ avahi-browse -ar
+   eth0 IPv6 cubox-i [d0:63:b4:00:88:1f]                   Workstation          local
+   eth0 IPv4 cubox-i [d0:63:b4:00:88:1f]                   Workstation          local
=   eth0 IPv6 cubox-i [d0:63:b4:00:88:1f]                   Workstation          local
   hostname = [cubox-i.local]
   address = [fe80::d263:b4ff:fe00:881f]
   port = [9]
   txt = []
=   eth0 IPv4 cubox-i [d0:63:b4:00:88:1f]                   Workstation          local
   hostname = [cubox-i.local]
   address = [192.168.0.25]
   port = [9]
   txt = []
```

My problem is that I also need to have avahi discovering working, but as can be seen, avahi-browse doesn't list the link-local address, why? How to make it list the link-local address too, since in this case the static configuration (192.168.0.25) is of no use.

Answer (score 1):

The truth is that I can access the static IP 192.168.0.25! The issue was that I was trying to communicate using direct cable while my notebook was connected to WiFi, inside a 192.168.0.0/24 network. When turning off WiFi I'm able to access 192.168.0.25.